# Add toast when an image is Saved Eclipse

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app that can take photos. Once the user clicks "Save" I simply want a toast message to appear.

The current code works to take the photo but I want to implement the toast code below when the user saves the image into the camera folder. Any ideas how I would do this.

Below is the source code to take the photo:

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
public void onClickbtnCamera(View v){
  Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
  Uri uriSavedImage=Uri.fromFile(
    new  File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera","QR_"+timeStamp+ ".png"));
  imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
  startActivityForResult(imageIntent, 1);
}
```

The toast I want to show:

```
Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
             "Picture was taking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 100, 0);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `startActivityForResult()` you will get response in `onActivityResult()` method inside the Activity. Try this sample code.

```
          @Override
          public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {

          //Check for succesful result code
          //replace getResources().getInteger(R.integer.success) with the actual resultCode
          if (resultCode == getResources().getInteger(R.integer.success)) {
            //Show your Toast when the result is a success.
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Picture was taking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 100, 0);
            toast.show();
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error under `(R.integer.success)` basically as a result of the integer not existing. What should I do. Thanks

Comment: yes definitely. that was my custom code, Put out  a log to check what is the value of resultCode when your operation is succesful and use that value in the code.

Comment: onActivityResult has different resultCode for different operations. Since I didn't run your code, I don't know what will be the actual value of resultCode. Can you please try and get the value of resultCode ?

Comment: I am new at android development so I'm not sure how I would go about doing this would you explain how I would go about doing this.

Comment: put a log inside onActivityResult method and see what is the value of resultCode ?

Comment: replace  getResources().getInteger(R.integer.success) with -1 and check if you are able to display the toast. i.e check if resultCode== -1

Comment: @CraigGallagher: hey..were you able to display the Toast?

Comment: Just tried it there and it worked thanks for that :)